# How to start output a new line and then go back up to the previous line java

Tags: java

Im doing a English to braille program. This is how im doing it

```
    if(letter_saver.contains("a")){
            System.out.println("|. |");
            System.out.println("|..|");
            System.out.println("| .|");
```

it out prints

```
|. |  //but i need to be able to come back to this line to do the next letter  
|..|  
| .|
```

Instead of it printing it down here.

Comment: What out put you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not going to be able to accomplish this using System.out.print.

Instead, you'll need some other variable to hold your text while you're working on it.

I'd recommend using a string array (or ArrayList if you don't know how many lines there will be in advance), with each entry corresponding to a line of text.

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
lines.add("|. |");
lines.add("|..|");
lines.add("| .|");
```

This way, you can easily go back to edit a previous line as follows:

```
lines.set(0, lines.get(0).concat("text to add"); // Edit a previous line
```

Then, when you're ready to display the results:

```
for(String s : lines)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object which has separate objects for each line. Input a string and convert the string into braille with three loops. Each loop calls a different line and builds a string. This allows you to add new characters without manually adding the characters.

```
public class Braille {
    char letter;
    String lineOne;
    String lineTwo;
    String lineThree;
    //More variables if necessary

    public Braille(char letter, String lineOne, String lineTwo, String lineThree){
        this.letter = letter;
        this.lineOne = lineOne;
        this.lineTwo = lineTwo;
        this.lineThree = lineThree;
    }
    public char getLetter(){
        return letter;
    }
    public String getLineOne(){
        return lineOne;
    }
    public String getLineTwo(){
        return lineTwo;
    }
    public String getLineThree(){
        return lineThree;
    }
}
```

Then create a new object to represent a letter.

```
Braille a = new Braille('a', "|. |", "|..|", "| .|");
//A data structure to store the letters is necessary.
ArrayList<Braille> brailleLetters = new ArrayList<Braille>();
brailleLetters.add(a);

public Braille getLetter(char letter){
    int index = 0;
    while(index < brailleLetters.size()){
        if(brailleLetters.get(index) == letter){
            return brailleLetters.get(index);
        index++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

With three loops each line can be build by calling the appropriate getLine function. Letters are easily stored and strings can be easily converted.

```
String convertString = "Test";
String lineOne = "";
String lineTwo = "";
String lineThree = "";
int index = 0;
while(index < convertString.length){
    lineOne += getLetter(converString.getCharAt(index)).getLineOne();
    index++;
}
//More loops needed based on number of lines.
```

*I haven't run this code but something like this will work.*